# Wrong numbering of sections - html export - org-mode - RTL languages

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html, right-to-left

This small example:

```
#+LANGUAGE: ar
#+HTML: <style>  html,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,body { direction: rtl} </style>

*  1

**  - 1. 1 

**  - 1. 2 !

**  - 1. 3 !

* 2

** - 2. 1 !

** - 2. 2 

** - 2. 3 !
```

The html-export of org-mode looks like this:

[image: errors in numbering]

It writes correctly: from right to left (rtl language: arabic).

The problem is at the 2nd and 3rd subsection of section 1.
And at the 1st and 3rd subsection of section 2.

For example: at the 2nd subsection of the 1st section:

We should see at the beginning (that's on the right!) of the line the 1 *then* the 2.
But as you can see in the picture: the numbering is 2 and then 1.
(Same problem by 1.3., 2.1 and 2.3)

Also from the picture we see: There isn't a problem in the order of the numbering of "1. 2." [notice the space after the dot].  Somehow "1.2" [without space] is interpreted as an LTR-word (?)

Should I add something else in the header of the org file?
Or should i change the resulted html file?

This is from it:

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#org6738c81">1.1. - 1. 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#orga620619">1.2. - 1. 2 !</a></li>
<li><a href="#org6512339">1.3. - 1. 3 !</a></li>
</ul>
```